# combining css selectors to show/hide siblings

Tags: css, css-selectors, sass

I'm using jqUI to build an app with a content pane and side-menu.

When the page is showing the list, I want to hide some of the menu content, but when the page is showing an item, I want to show the menu content.

I've created a pretty basic jsfiddle as an example http://jsfiddle.net/pq83M/8/

I DON'T want to do this in javascript, as the page transitions are in the jqui library and I don't think it's effective to listen for this specific transition separately fro the others.

What I am hoping to figure out is a way of saying

when

```
div#content > div#list_item.active ~ div#menu > div#list_item_details {
  display:block;
}
```

with the caveat that the `~` is looking for the sibling of `div#content`, not the sibling of `div#list_item.active`.

I'm using Sass, so those custom selectors are available.

Comment: I haven't heard of any custom selectors that are provided by Sass.

Comment: @BoltClock May be he means `mixins` or Compass?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to find siblings based on the parent (`div#content`) but only start with particular parents depending on their children (`div#list_item.active`).

If so, it's not possible in CSS Selector Level 3, but it's coming in CSS Selectors Level 4; you'll be able to select the subject of your operation/comparison. http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors4/#subject